# symfony route import with allowable null prefix does not work

Tags: php, routes, symfony4, prefix

when importing routes from a resource file with a prefix, symfony will not match a valid route
with an empty prefix unless the URL has a double / in it (//).

How to reproduce
Given this setting:

```
web:
  resource: '_routes.yaml'
  prefix: /{route_prefix?}
  requirements:
    route_prefix: valueA|valueB
```

and _routes.yaml:

```
product_list:
  path: '/brands/{brand_name}/{id}.html'
  controller: App\Controller\Brand\ProductController::index
```

the router will match:
`/valueA/brands/{brand_name}/{id}.html` and
`/valueB/brands/{brand_name}/{id}.html` but will **not match**
`/brands/{brand_name}/{id}.html` unless you provide the URL like this:
`//brands/{brand_name}/{id}.html`

Is it really a bug or something I do not understand?

Comment: I would have removed the extra `/` in `/brands` and add one after `valueA` and `valueB`. Here it's normal : One side you have `/` + valueA + `/brands` and on the other side you have `/` +`/brands` so obviously you have two slashes. PS: There is nothing wrong with that question, again a down vote for nothing.

Comment: tried that, it does not work. I looked at the generated ```UrlMatcher.php``` class and the ```/``` are in there. It seems to me symfony will add the ```/``` regardless